# Strange form of control operation - java

Tags: java

I'm making a game in Java - I have control characters, but it works very strange. When I turn the game - control is not established. I have to minimize the game, come back to it and then the control is work! Maybe someone knows why?
I add some code in which there may be something wrong (the compiler does not detect errors!)

Game Window:

```js
package game;
 
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;
 
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
 
/**
 * Tworzenie okna gry
 * @author szaroket
 */
 
public class GameFrame extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
 
    private GameBar game_bar;
    private TileMap map;
    private Timer timer;
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Player player;
    Controller con;
 
    public float power = 1f;
    public int yspeed = 0;
    public int xspeed = 0;
    public float gravity = 0.1f;
    public float friction = 0.95f;
 
    /**
     * Tworzy elementy planszy oraz przyciski.
     * 
     * @param parent Sprawia, że ten panel jest w stanie wywołać metody jego rodzica.
     * @throws IOException
     */
 
    public GameFrame(MainMenu parent) throws IOException{
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.insets = new Insets(0,400,0,0); 
 
        map = new TileMap("Map.txt", 32);
        player = new Player();
        con = new Controller();
 
 
        game_bar=new GameBar(parent);
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        add(game_bar, constraints);
 
        this.setOpaque(false);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(con);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
 
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }
 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Player.player_y ++;
        repaint();        
        ckeck_controls();
    }
 
    private void ckeck_controls() {
        if(con.down){
            yspeed += power;
        }
        if(con.up){
            yspeed -= power;
        }
        if(con.right){
            xspeed += power;
        }
        if(con.left){
            xspeed -= power;
        }
 
        //yspeed += gravity;
 
        Player.player_x += xspeed;
        Player.player_y += yspeed;
 
    }
 
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(getParent().getSize());
    }
 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        map.draw(g);
        game_bar.repaint();
        getParent().repaint();
 
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
 
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillOval((int) Player.player_x, (int) Player.player_y, 40, 40);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```js
package game;
 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
 
public class Controller implements KeyListener{
     //public int power = 1;
     //public int yspeed = 0;
     //public int xspeed = 0;
     //public float gravity = 0.1f;
 
     boolean left = false;
     boolean right = false;
     boolean down = false;
     boolean up = false;
 
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            //Player.player_x += power;
            //xspeed += power;
            right = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            //Player.player_x -= power;
            //xspeed -= power;
            left = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            //Player.player_y -= power;
            //yspeed -= power;
            up = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            //Player.player_y += power;
            //yspeed += power;
            down = false;
        }
    }
 
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            //Player.player_x += power;
            //xspeed += power;
            right = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            //Player.player_x -= power;
            //xspeed -= power;
            left = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            //Player.player_y -= power;
            //yspeed -= power;
            up = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            //Player.player_y += power;
            //yspeed += power;
            down = true;
        }
 
        //yspeed += gravity;
 
        //Player.player_x += xspeed;
        //Player.player_y += yspeed;
    }
 
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {        
    }
 
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `requestFocusInWindow()` is returning `false`. This means that the request was unsuccessful.  You need to make sure you call `requestFocusInWindow()` AFTER the frame is already displayed.

So, once you call `JFrame.setVisible(true)`, THEN call `requestFocusInWindow()` and it should give focus properly.

Comment: It seems to me that I have this in right configuration. 
You think that can be sth else?